# New TextView created when using setText to a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a `TextView` in my Android app . When I use `setText()` to the old text of the `TextView` still appear and the new text is written on it. If I close the screen of the phone and opens it after a small period of time the old text of `TextView` disappeared.

[image]

How can I solve that?

The grey is the old text of `TextView` and the green is the new text of the `TextView`

this is the xml code :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/challengeStateInResultActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:text="جارى التحميل ..."
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

and this is the presenter code :

```
     fireStoreChallenges.document(challengeId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                final long opponentScore = documentSnapshot.getLong("player1score");

                String player1uid = documentSnapshot.getString("player1Uid");
                fireStoreUsers.document(player1uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            String opponentName = document.getString("userName");
                            String opponentImage = document.getString("userImage");

                            view.setOpponentData(opponentScore, opponentName, opponentImage);
                        }
                    }
                });

                int opponentScoreInt = (int) opponentScore;

                if (score == opponentScoreInt) {
                    view.setChallengeTvText(drawChallengeText);
                } else {
                    if (score > opponentScoreInt) {
                        view.setChallengeTvText(wonChallengeText);
                        view.setChallengeTvBGColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    } else {
                        view.setChallengeTvText(loseChallengeText);
                        view.setChallengeTvBGColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is the method in the view :

```
@Override
public void setChallengeTvText(String text) {
    challengeStateTv.setText(text);
    challengeStateTv.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code please?

Answer (score 0):

To update the previous text,you can update the TextView with

> `TextView.setText("NEW_TEXT");`

Code Example:

```
TextView tv;

// inside OnCreate method
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView) // link to your xml TextView Definition

// to clear the TextView you can use as below
// tv.setText("");

// to set Text as "Hello" 
tv.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: its not neccessary... you can use just `tv.setText("Hello");` edited my answer to avoid confusion...